# Ninject and binding with generics

Tags: generics, binding, ninject

I have a assembly and needs to bind all classes from that assembly to some generic class. How this can be done ? For now I am binding it using statements like -

```
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<Villa>>().Named("GetVillaList");
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<Center>>().Named("GetCentreList");
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<ExtraDetail>>().Named("GetExtraDetail");
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<Airline>>().Named("GetAirLineList");
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<Airport>>().Named("GetAirportList");
        Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To<VillaPlus.BusinessLayer.Generic.Command.GenericFetch<Title>>().Named("GetTitleList");
```

How this can be done with single bind statement in for loop ? I have all classes types available from the loaded assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Ninject.Extensions.Conventions` to select the classes and then bind with a custom `IBindingGenerator` to find the type to bind to and name it.

Include the [Conventions](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.conventions/3.2.0) library and then in your startup:

```
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind(config =>
        {
            config.FromThisAssembly()
                .Select(t => typeof(IMessage).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass)
                .BindWith(new BindingGenerator());
        });

    var commands = kernel.GetAll<ICommand>();
    var villaCommand = kernel.Get<ICommand>("GetVillaList");
```

this assumes all the classes you want to bind implement `IMessage`

```
public class Villa : IMessage
{
}
```

then the BindingGenerator:

```
public class BindingGenerator : IBindingGenerator
{
    public IEnumerable<IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>> CreateBindings(Type type, IBindingRoot bindingRoot)
    {
        var genericType = typeof(GenericFetch<>);
        var concreteType = genericType.MakeGenericType(type);

        var bindings = bindingRoot.Bind(typeof(ICommand)).To(concreteType).Named("Get" + type.Name + "List");
        return new[] { (IBindingWhenInNamedWithOrOnSyntax<object>)bindings };
    }
}
```